# What does "Say women" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, Megyn admits that she too face sexual harrashment from Roger,
Fox News CEO, but she refuse to be the  poster girl
for sexual harassment:

> Megyn: I mean, going on the record...It's basically admitting you're
> the weak one in the herd.
>
> Gil Norman: No, it's admitting you're the hot one.
>
> Megyn: It has nothing to do with that, Gil.
>
> Gil Norman: **Say women.**

What does "Say women" mean? I think He’s implying that women say that being sexually harassed has nothing to with being hot.

Comment: Yes, I think he probably is. "So women say" would be a more usual way to express it.

Comment: Say women = That is what women say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Say women” = “That is something women would say”

Answer (score 0):

Phrases like this starting with "Say" or "Says" cpnvey a certain degree of disbelief. So Gil is implying that this is something women say but he does not personally agree with it (I assume Gil is a man). People do say "Says you" to disagree with the speaker.